# SQL Geography Performance Issues while filtering by radius

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have this simple SQL table with 10,000,000 records in:

```
create table locationtests
(
    Id int not null identity(1,1) primary key,
    Localization geography not null
);
```

The records are calculated and inserted randomly starting from a couple of minimum and maximum Latitude and Longitude with this function:

```
DECLARE @counter BIGINT;
SELECT @counter = COUNT(*) from locationtests;
print(@counter)
WHILE(@counter != 1000000)
BEGIN
    DECLARE @latitude varchar(MAX); 
    SET @latitude = (RAND() * (47.66202 - 28.39222)) + 28.39222 /*latitude*/
    DECLARE @longitude varchar(MAX);
    SET @longitude = (RAND() * (-122.14082 - -80.60771)) + -80.60771 /*longitude*/
    DECLARE @stringToInsert varchar(MAX);
    SET @stringToInsert = 'POINT('+ @longitude + ' ' + @latitude +')';
    INSERT INTO [locationtests] VALUES (geography::STGeomFromText(@stringToInsert,4326), @stringToInsert);
    SET @counter += 1;
END
GO
```

Take note that this table have a spatial index on Location column.

But, when I'm doing a select (search) with radius using this query:

```
DECLARE @Origin GEOGRAPHY, @Distance INTEGER = 400000, @Points Varchar(MAX) = 'POINT(-122.14082' +' '+ '47.66202)';
SET @Origin = geography::STGeomFromText(@Points,4326)
select Localization FROM locationtests where @Origin.STDistance(Localization) <= @Distance;
```

And there is the execution plan:

[image: i]

Honestly I don't know how and what optimize in this query...
Do you have any ideas ?

Comment: Might be worth looking at solr or elasticsearch for spatial searches.

Comment: Did you create a [spatial index](http://sqlbits.com/Sessions/Event5/creating_high_performance_spatial_databases)?

Comment: Yeah, i've created the spatial index, without any substantial differences...

Comment: Does this help at all `select Localization FROM locationtests whereLocalization.STDistance( @Origin) <= @Distance`?

Comment: The picture of the query plan is tiny, but I'm not seeing your spatial index being used. Try forcing it with a query hint and see if that improves. Also, I've also had good luck using an STIntersects query for this (first creating a disc with the desired radius centered at your search point). But they should (in theory) be equivalent.

Comment: ErikPhilips , nothing to do, is the same thing.

@BenThul , i've tried to force the index with the specific clause, but the results are still the same...i'm thinking about the solution that you've proposed...
So, it's a bounding box? how i can use this with my system that need to search all points around a stablished Geography point  starting from a maximum radius?

Can you explain me how to do that?


Thanks.

Comment: @VirtApp: Two things: to be clear about forcing the index, I meant with something like `WITH (INDEX = your_spatial_index)`. If that's what you're doing, so be it. If you haven't tried it yet, give it a shot. Secondly, here's a bare bones implementation of the approach I mentioned: `declare @disc geography = @points.STBuffer(@Distance); select Localization FROM locationtests where Localization.STIntersects(@disc) = 1`

Comment: Your query plan shows that the spatial index is already used. I have a similar execution plan on my system and it returns 18000 rows in less than 1 second (versus 41 seconds without the spatial index). I don't think there is anything to optimize here.

Comment: @RazvanSocol Thanks!
I'm wondering if i will separate the two tables: one for the account details and one for the geolocalization, zip etc... values this will be better and fast instead of putting all into the same table?